# Sending input data to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, send

My following code is this:

```
<form>
    <input class="inputField" type="text" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myButton").on("click", function () {
            var value = $(".inputField").val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to send to the file main.js the data after a user puts in some information in the input and clicks on the submit button. I tried with an ajax() method but it doesn't work or I don't know how to do this. After I send it to the main.js file I want to access that information. Anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: where is this `main.js` and how does it relate to any of this? since you haven't mentioned node, you're dealing with purely client-side JS, and you can't "send" to a .js file...

Comment: The main.js file is in the same project, i press ctrl+f5 and compile, i want to send information to that file.

Comment: Usually you send data to the server to process (not to a file). Do you want to save data in a file on a client's computer?

Comment: After i compile the project on a localserver(my computer), i want it to send to main.js.

Comment: yes, i want to save the data on a client's computer in the main.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "send" the input field value to main.js by passing the input field value as a parameter to a function in main.js.

main.js:

```
function mainjsfunction(inputFieldValue)
{
    console.log(inputFieldValue);  
    //do something with input field value
}
```

html:

```
<form>
    <input class="inputField" type="text" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myButton").on("click", function () {
            var value = $(".inputField").val();
            mainjsfunction(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```